# What determined the closest-approach distance between New Horizons and Pluto?

Tags: new-horizons, pluto

New Horizons passed 7,750 mi (12,472 km) from the surface of Pluto at its closest approach, [limiting](https://gizmodo.com/new-horizons-will-get-incredibly-close-to-its-next-targ-1800903259) the image resolution to about 600 feet (183 m).  **What set the specific closest-approach distance?**  And in particular, why wasn't an even closer trajectory chosen to improve the detail of the data gathered as is being done for its upcoming encounter with Ultima Thule, where the closest approach will be 2,175 miles (3,500 km), giving a resolution of 230 feet (70 m).

[The top answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/9055/19169) to a [previous question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/9054/why-doesnt-the-new-horizons-probe-fly-any-nearer-than-10-000-km-from-pluto?rq=1) about the Pluto closest-approach distance suggested that New Horizon's cameras wouldn't be able to cleanly image Pluto at such a short distance and vast speeds.  But this explanation would imply that a similarly long distance with Ultima Thule should be maintained.  **A satisfying answer to the question needs to address what makes Pluto different from Ultima Thule.**

A lot of the discussion of the internet seems to suggest that this has something to do with the risk of hitting debris, but this [quote from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Horizons#Outer_Solar_System) says that debris risk could have been reduced by passing *closer* to Pluto.

> If the hazard increased, New Horizons could have used ...possible
>   contingency plans ... the probe ... could have positioned its antenna
>   to make a course correction that would take it just 3000 km from the
>   surface of Pluto where it was expected that the atmospheric drag would
>   clean the surrounding space of possible debris.

If it's really about collision avoidance, I am interested in whether anyone knows details about the differences in debris between the Pluto and Ultima Thule systems.

Comment: Doesn't the second answer to the linked question (https://space.stackexchange.com/a/9118/897) provide the detail you want?

Comment: nevermind, found some data. I'll answer the other question, then we can close this as a duplicate.

Comment: The 12,472 km distance seems too close to actually pass through the 17,536 km orbit of Charon unless the orbital plane is tilted even more than is illustrated in that slide. And it doesn't explain why they didn't pass within 3,000 km of Pluto (which was expected to be cleared by the atmosphere) if, as evidenced by the Ultima Thule plan, the cameras can indeed image cleanly at that distance.